# Get the last ID from Multiple Stored Procedures Executed

Tags: sql-server, xml

So I have an XML file , to take data from it and insert into tables.
For this I’ve created 3 procedures(`INSERTXMLMultipleTables`,`INSERTXMLNIAC`,`INSERTNIACFORCOMPONENTS`).

The logic of these procedure is that the first two just insert simple data into table, have an unique ID, the last one (`INSERTNIACFORCOMPONENTS`) works like this(`INSERTNIACFORCOMPONENTS`->`INSERTXMLMultipleTables`+`INSERTXMLNIAC`).

`INSERTNIACFORCOMPONENTS` just inserts all the ids from other tables into NIACtoComponents table, so they could be linked to `NIAC`.

So, with these 3 procedures I insert data just from one NIAC node.

Now, I have to do this task, but for all `NIAC` nodes(suppose there are 50-70 `NIAC`s).
For this I've creted the last SP(`InsertforNIACList`)
I’ve tried to count the number of `NIAC`s inside the `NIACList`, so then I could insert them into the last table(`NIACList`).

I’ve wanted to retrieve the `id`(`idniac`) from the `NIACFORCOMPONENTS` using `scope_identity()`, to use it in insertion for the `NIACList` table, but it failed, and I don’t know why.
Bellow I will attach my SP code to understand better the situation:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[InsertXMLMultipleTables]
(
@idAddress1 int out,
@idAddress2 int out,
@idactivities int out,
@idgoods int out,
@idmobileunit int out,
@idcommercial int out,
@idcommercialut int out,
@idpsu int out,
@idmerchant int out,
@xml xml
)
as 


begin 
set nocount on

INSERT INTO Activities(Code,Name)
        SELECT  
    
Code=c.value('Code[1]','nvarchar(90)') ,
Name=c.value('Name[1]','nvarchar(90)') 
FROM @xml.nodes('/NIACList/NIAC/CommercialUnit/Activities/Activity') Activities(c)
set @IDActivities=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
end;




begin
INSERT INTO Address(Region,Locality,Street,House,Block,Flat,Phone,Fax,Email)
        SELECT 
        Region=c.value('Region[1],','nvarchar(60)'),
        Locality=c.value('Locality[1],','nvarchar(50)') ,
        Street=c.value('Street[1],','nvarchar(60)') ,
        House=c.value('House[1],','nvarchar(10)') ,
        Block=c.value('Block[1],','nvarchar(10)') ,
        Flat=c.value('Flat[1],','nvarchar(10)') ,
        Phone=c.value('Phone[1],','nvarchar(30)') ,
        Fax=c.value('Fax[1],','nvarchar(60)') ,
        Email=c.value('Email[1],','nvarchar(60)') 
    FROM @xml.nodes('NIACList/NIAC/Merchant/Address') Address(c)
    set @idAddress1=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    end;

    begin
    INSERT INTO Merchant(IDNX,Name,WorkProgram,IdAddress)
        SELECT 
        Region=c.value('IDNx[1],','nvarchar(max)'),
        Locality=c.value('Name[1],','nvarchar(max)') ,
        Street=c.value('WorkProgram[1],','datetime2') ,
        @idAddress1
    FROM @xml.nodes('NIACList/NIAC/Merchant') Merchant(c)
    set @idmerchant=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    end;

    
begin
INSERT INTO Address(Region,Locality,Street,House,Block,Flat,Phone,Fax,Email)
        SELECT 
        Region=c.value('Region[1],','nvarchar(60)'),
        Locality=c.value('Locality[1],','nvarchar(50)') ,
        Street=c.value('Street[1],','nvarchar(60)') ,
        House=c.value('House[1],','nvarchar(10)') ,
        Block=c.value('Block[1],','nvarchar(10)') ,
        Flat=c.value('Flat[1],','nvarchar(10)') ,
        Phone=c.value('Phone[1],','nvarchar(30)') ,
        Fax=c.value('Fax[1],','nvarchar(60)') ,
        Email=c.value('Email[1],','nvarchar(60)')   
    FROM @xml.nodes('NIACList/NIAC/CommercialUnit/Address') Address(c)
    set @idAddress2=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    set @idcommercialut=SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    end;


    begin
    INSERT INTO CommercialApparatus(Count,Length,Width,Height )
        SELECT      
    Count =c.value('Type[1]','int') ,
        Length=c.value('Length[1]','int') ,
         Width=c.value('Width[1]','int') ,
         Height=c.value('Height[1]','int') 
    FROM @xml.nodes('/NIACList/NIAC/CommercialUnit/CommercialApparatus') CommercialApparatus(c)
    set @idcommercial=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    end;




    begin
    INSERT INTO Goods(Name)
        SELECT 
        Name=c.value('Name[1]','nvarchar(60)') 
    FROM @xml.nodes('/NIACList/NIAC/CommercialUnit/Goods/Good') Goods(c)
    set @idgoods=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    end;

    begin
    INSERT INTO MobileUnit(Type,Length,Width,Height )
        SELECT  
    Type =c.value('Type[1]','int') ,
        Length=c.value('Length[1]','int') ,
         Width=c.value('Width[1]','int') ,
         Height=c.value('Height[1]','int') 
    FROM @xml.nodes('/NIACList/NIAC/CommercialUnit/MobileUnit') MobileUnit(c)
         set @idmobileunit=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    end;



    begin
    INSERT INTO PublicSupplyUnit(Capacity,TerraceCapacity)
        SELECT 
        Capacity=c.value('Capacity[1]','int') ,
        TerraceCapacity=c.value('TerraceCapacity[1]','int')
    FROM @xml.nodes('/NIACList/NIAC/CommercialUnit/PublicSupplyUnit') PublicSupplyUnit(c)
    set @idpsu=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    end;



    begin
    INSERT INTO CommercialUnit(IDNX,Name,Type,Area,Location,TerraceCapacity,TradingAlcohol,TradingBeer,TradingTobaccoProducts,AmbulatoryTrading,MobileUnitTrading,CommercialApparatusTrading,IDActivities,IdAddress,IDCommercial,IDGoods,IDMobileUnit,IDPSU)
        SELECT 
        IDNx=c.value('IDNx[1],','nvarchar(90)'),
        Name=c.value('Name[1],','nvarchar(90)') ,
        Type=c.value('Type[1],','nvarchar(90)') ,
        Area=c.value('Area[1],','int') ,
        Location=c.value('Location[1],','nvarchar(max)'),
        TerraceCapacity=c.value('TerraceCapacity[1],','float') ,
        TradingAlcohol=c.value('TradingAlcohol[1],','bit') ,
        TradingBeer=c.value('TradingBeer[1],','bit') ,
        TradingTobaccoProducts=c.value('TradingTobaccoProducts[1],','bit'),
        AmbulatoryTrading=c.value('AmbulatoryTrading[1],','bit') ,
        MobileUnitTrading=c.value('MobileUnitTrading[1],','bit') ,
        CommercialApparatusTrading=c.value('CommercialApparatusTrading[1],','bit') ,
        @idactivities,@idAddress2,@idcommercial,@idgoods,@idmobileunit,@idpsu
    FROM @xml.nodes('NIACList/NIAC/CommercialUnit') CommercialUnit(c)
    end;


GO

CREATE procedure [dbo].[InsertXMLNIAC]
(
@xml xml,
@idNIAC int output,
@idCessation int output
)
as 

begin 
set nocount on


INSERT INTO NIAC(Number,SubmissionDate,ExpirationDate,IssuerIDNO,IssuerName,SuspensionPeriod,Modifications)
        SELECT 
        Number=c.value('Number[1],','nvarchar(80)'),
        SubmissionDate=c.value('SubmissionDate[1],','datetime2') ,
        ExpirationDate=c.value('ExpirationDate[1],','datetime2') ,
        IssuerIDNO=c.value('IssuerIDNO[1],','nvarchar(max)') ,
        IssuerName=c.value('IssuerName[1],','nvarchar(60)') ,
        SuspensionPeriod=c.value('SuspensionPeriod[1],','datetime2') ,
        Modifications=c.value('Modifications[1],','nvarchar(60)') 
    FROM @xml.nodes('NIACList/NIAC') NIAC(c)
    set @idNIAC=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    end;

    begin
    INSERT INTO Cessation(Basis,Date,IDNIAC)
        SELECT 
        Basis=c.value('Basis[1],','nvarchar(60)'),
        Date=c.value('Date[1],','date') ,      
        @idNIAC
    FROM @xml.nodes('NIACList/NIAC/Cessation') Cessation(c)
    set @idCessation=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    end;

GO


CREATE procedure [dbo].[NIACFORCOMPONENTS]
@xml xml,
@idNIAC int out
        

AS
BEGIN
declare
    
        @idCessation int ,
        @idmerchant int ,
        @idAddress1 int ,
        @idAddress2 int,
        @idcommercialut int,
        @idactivities int,
        @idgoods int,
        @idmobileunit int,
        @idcommercial int,
        @idpsu int


    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    declare @trancount int;
    set @trancount=@@TRANCOUNT;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    EXEC [dbo].[InsertXMLMultipleTables]
        @idAddress1 = @idAddress1 OUTPUT,
        @idAddress2 = @idAddress2 OUTPUT,
        @IDActivities = @idactivities OUTPUT,
        @idgoods = @idgoods OUTPUT,
        @idmobileunit = @idmobileunit OUTPUT,
        @idcommercial = @idcommercial OUTPUT,
        @idcommercialut = @idcommercialut OUTPUT,
        @idpsu = @idpsu OUTPUT,
        @idmerchant = @idmerchant OUTPUT,
        @xml = @xml


        EXEC [dbo].[InsertXMLNIAC]
        
        @idNIAC = @idNIAC OUTPUT,
        @idCessation = @idCessation OUTPUT,
        @xml=@xml

     
    
         begin try
        if @trancount = 0
            begin transaction
        else
            save transaction NIACFORCOMPONENTS;

        

lbexit:
        if @trancount = 0   
            commit;
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(),
                 @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @xstate = XACT_STATE();
        if @xstate = -1
            rollback;
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0
            rollback
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0
            rollback transaction NIACFORCOMPONENTS;

        raiserror ('NIACFORCOMPONENTS: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
        return;
    end catch   
    
    Begin
                              
        INSERT INTO NIACToComponents(IDNIAC,IdCessation,IdMerchant,IDAddressMerchant,IDAddressCU,IDCommercialUt,IDActivities,IDGoods,IDMobileUnit,IDCommercial,IDPSU)
        SELECT 
        @idNIAC as N'@idNIAC',
        @idCessation as N'@idCessation',
        @idmerchant as N'@idmerchant',
        @idAddress1 as N'@idAddress1',
        @idAddress2 as N'@idAddress2',
        @idcommercialut as N'@idcommercialut',
        @idactivities as N'@idactivities',
        @idgoods as N'@idgoods',
        @idmobileunit as N'@idmobileunit',
        @idcommercial as N'@idcommercial',
        @idpsu as N'@idpsu'

    COMMIT

    
        END             
END


CREATE procedure [dbo].[InsertforNIACLIST]
@xml xml,
@idNIAC int out 
as
begin
EXEC [dbo].[NIACFORCOMPONENTS]
@xml = @xml,
@idniac=@idniac output

set @idniac=SCOPE_IDENTITY();



DECLARE @cnt INT, @i INT;

SET @cnt = @xml.value('count(NIACList/NIAC)', 'INT');

SET @i = 1;
WHILE @i <= @cnt
BEGIN

INSERT INTO NIACList(IDNIAC)
    SELECT 
    @idNIAC
    FROM @xml.nodes('NIACList/NIAC[sql:variable("@i")]') AS NIACList(c)
   SET @i += 1;

END

select *from NIACList

END
```

**UPDATE**

So i've tried differently, and I've could do the count process of `NIAC`s inside `NIACList` using table variables, and now I want to use that code into an `INSERT` scope, how can I do this?

Bellow is the code for the update:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[InsertforNIACLIST]
@xml xml,
@idNIAC int out 
as
begin
EXEC [dbo].[NIACFORCOMPONENTS]
@xml=@xml,
@idniac=@idNIAC output

DECLARE @temp TABLE (xml xml);



INSERT @temp VALUES (@xml);


WITH NIACList AS
(
    SELECT n.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(256)') IDNIAC
        FROM @temp t
        CROSS APPLY t.xml.nodes('/NIACList/*') x(n)
)
SELECT IDNIAC, count(*) cnt
    FROM NIACList
    GROUP BY IDNIAC;
```

Comment: scope_identity needs to follow directly after an insert statement or it just doesn't work (following an exec like that won't work at all).  Use an output parameter as you have done in some of the other stored procedures or start using the output clause if you prefer that instead.  Either way, the change will need to be made to the stored procedure that actually does the inserting, not the caller.

Comment: Well I thought about that, and also tried, but it doesn't insert the idniac into the NIACList table, just the incremented value of the id from the table(IDNIACList).Maybe because my specifications in the INSERT scope are not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OUTPUT to solve this kind of problem
the example below

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO

DECLARE @MyTableVar TABLE (
    NewScrapReasonID SMALLINT,  
    Name VARCHAR(50),  
    ModifiedDate DATETIME); 
    
INSERT Production.ScrapReason  
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ScrapReasonID, INSERTED.Name, INSERTED.ModifiedDate  
        INTO @MyTableVar  
VALUES (N'Operator error', GETDATE());  
  
--Display the result set of the table variable.  
SELECT NewScrapReasonID, Name, ModifiedDate FROM @MyTableVar;  
--Display the result set of the table.  
SELECT ScrapReasonID, Name, ModifiedDate   
FROM Production.ScrapReason;  
GO
```